# Error from division operator

Tags: python

So, Im quite new to python 3.5.0, recently Ive been working on a sleep calculator, however Ive encountered an issue, this is my code so far... its been annotated with tags/comments:

```
#sleep calculator, user enters there hours slept over a nicght and the   program
#will work out different facts about there sleaping
print("Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...")
hourspernight = int(input("how many hours per night do you sleep?"))
#variable for the hours per week slept
hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
#telling the user how many hours er week they sleep
print ("you sleep", hoursperweek,"hours per week")
#variable for how many hours per month they sleep
hourspermonth = float(hoursperweek * 4.35)
#teling the user how namy hours per month they sleep
hourspermonth = print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
#ISSUE, this is the variable that python has a problem with, and I'm not sure why
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
#telling the user how many days per month they sleep (this bits ok... I think)
dayspermonth = print("you sleep for",dayspermonth,"days per month aswell!")
```

error given:

```
========================= RESTART: F:/sleep hours.py 

=========================
Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...
how many hours per night do you sleep?8
you sleep 56 hours per week
you also sleep 243.59999999999997 hours per month
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/sleep hours.py", line 14, in <module>
    dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

**UPDATE:**

It's no longer giving an error, but the days per month doesn't look like the correct answer, is this correct?

========================= RESTART: F:/sleep hours.py =========================

```
Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...
how many hours per night do you sleep?8
you sleep 56 hours per week
you also sleep 243.59999999999997 hours per month
you sleep for 730.8 days per month aswell!
```

**UPDATE #2**

Everything's working great, but I'm not sure on the calculation for days per month, here's the line of code for it

```
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
```

If anyone could tell me if that's correct or not.

**UPDATE #3**

code now used:

```
# sleep calculator, user enters there hours slept over a nicght and the program
# will work out different facts about there sleaping
print("Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...")
hourspernight = int(input("how many hours per night do you sleep?"))
# variable for the hours per week slept
hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
# telling the user how many hours er week they sleep
print ("you sleep", hoursperweek,"hours per week")
# variable for how many hours per month they sleep
hourspermonth = float(hoursperweek * 4.35)
# teling the user how namy hours per month they sleep
print("you also sleep", "{0:.2f}".format(hourspermonth),"hours per month")
# variable for calculating the days per month slept
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / 24
# telling the user how many days per month they sleep
print("you sleep for","{0:.2f}".format(dayspermonth),"days per month aswell!")
```

the response from the shell:
    ========================= RESTART: F:/sleep hours.py =========================

```
Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...
how many hours per night do you sleep?8
you sleep 56 hours per week
you also sleep 243.60 hours per month
you sleep for 10.15 days per month aswell!
```

Comment: err. what's your problem, dude?

Comment: next time, please paste what python gave you as error

Comment: Check my edit for why you see `243.59999999999997`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you had was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

That's because on line 12 you put `hourspermonth = print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")`. Take out `hourspermonth` from your script. Same with last line.

```
#sleep calculator, user enters there hours slept over a nicght and the   program
#will work out different facts about there sleaping
print("Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...")
hourspernight = int(input("how many hours per night do you sleep?"))
#variable for the hours per week slept
hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
#telling the user how many hours er week they sleep
print ("you sleep", hoursperweek,"hours per week")
#variable for how many hours per month they sleep
hourspermonth = float(hoursperweek * 4.35)
#teling the user how namy hours per month they sleep
print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
#ISSUE, this is the variable that python has a problem with, and I'm not sure why
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
#telling the user how many days per month they sleep (this bits ok... I think)
print("you sleep for",dayspermonth,"days per month aswell!")
```

Side note: In python it's better if you make sense of your variables. Instead of using `hourspernight` use `hours_per_night` or even smaller `hrs_night` then next to it add comments if you need. Make it more presentable overall.

**Edit**

Change line 12 to:

```
print("you also sleep", "{0:.2f}".format(hourspermonth),"hours per month")
```

This will fix your format issue and make it 2 digits after the decimal point

**Edit 2**

Change line 14 and 16 to:

```
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / 24
...
print("you sleep for","{0:.2f}".format(dayspermonth),"days per month aswell!")
```

Comment: the calculation for dayspermonth is also wrong. Just saying.

Comment: But that is a logical issue. The OP has not even mentioned the error.

Comment: @AnandSKumar do you know the correct calculation for it... its also been driving me mental!

Comment: @ablyn how about now? for `dayspermonth`

Comment: ill give it a try, hold on

Answer (score 1):

2 of the lines causing issue are:-

```
hourspermonth = print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
```

and

```
dayspermonth = print("you sleep for",dayspermonth,"days per month aswell!")
```

calling `print` and assigning to a variable is not a valid syntax. Remove the assignment and just use print. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use only:

```
print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
```

Instead of:

```
hourspermonth = print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, firstly, you don't want to reassign the value of your variables when you print output, so just print. Like this:

```
# sleep calculator, user enters there hours slept over a nicght and the   program
# will work out different facts about there sleaping
print("Welcome to the sleep calculator, all you have to do is answer one question...")
hourspernight = int(input("how many hours per night do you sleep?"))
# variable for the hours per week slept
hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
# telling the user how many hours er week they sleep
print ("you sleep", hoursperweek,"hours per week")
# variable for how many hours per month they sleep
hourspermonth = float(hoursperweek * 4.35)
# teling the user how namy hours per month they sleep
print("you also sleep", hourspermonth,"hours per month")
# ISSUE, this is the variable that python has a problem with, and I'm not sure why
dayspermonth = (hourspermonth) / (hourspernight) * 24
# telling the user how many days per month they sleep (this bits ok... I think)
print("you sleep for",dayspermonth,"days per month as well!")
```

this works. Also, leave a space between `#` and the beginning of your comment.

Comment: NPs. Good luck. You can mark an answer as working by ticking it. That will let others know that you have accepted it.

Comment: will do, once Ive found the right calculation for the days per month, cuz i think that's wrong :/